# Three.js slow with thousands of objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating about 12,000 + BoxHelpers and the loading and, specially, the navigating is very slow. I want to know if there is a better approach

this is what I have

```
    var c=[];
c.push([    -100,15,285 ]);
c.push([    0,25.5,285  ]);
c.push([    0,51,285    ]);
c.push([    0,76.5,285  ]);
c.push([    0,0,297 ]);
c.push([    0,25.5,297  ]);
c.push([    0,51,297    ]);
```

.... this is for example only. actual data comes from json.

```
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10, 24.5, 12);


  for (var i in c)
        var cube = new THREE.BoxHelper();
    cube.material.color.set( 0x6666FF    );
    cube.scale.set( 5, 12, 6 );
    cube.position.set(c[i][0], c[i][1],c[i][2] );
    scene.add( cube );
    }
```

May be creating the whole building then just add the building to the scene? but I dont even know how to do start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanna create a Building out of thousands of objects?

If I get it correctly: 
- Create the Building in Blender and import it, or
- Create the Building out of ONE Geometry with thousands of vertices and faces

Can you upload an example Code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks. I use the merge function in Three.js to accomplish what I wanted.